# TypeError: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my below data which is having values and dates, but getting error

```
      Date      Subscriber
0   2017-08-01  168190046
1   2017-08-02  168773207
2   2017-08-03  169123818
3   2017-08-04  170301024

%matplotlib inline
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('LTE_Subs')
plt.scatter(df.Date,df.LTE_Subs,color='red',marker='+')
```

Comment: What is the error? And why have you used `df.LTE_Subs`, is there a column `LTE_Subs` ?

Comment: Change it to `plt.scatter(df.Date,df.Subscriber,color='red',marker='+')`

Comment: yes missed to rename the column (Subscriber=LTE_Subs)